# libGDX creating a minimap of a tiledmap

Tags: libgdx, tiled

I am developing a **top-down 2D game** with a **TiledMap**.

Currently i want to **create a minimap** of my TiledMap, but i´m really confused how to do this.

I´ve read something that i should create another camera, zoom out and render the map again, but how should i draw the zoomed out map in the upper right corner?

Am i overthinking this whole thing?

My Map:

```
public class LiquidMap {

private TiledMap                    map;
private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer  renderer;
private OrthographicCamera          camera = new OrthographicCamera();

private MiniMap miniMap;

public LiquidMap(String filePath) {
    map = new TmxMapLoader().load(filePath);

    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1 / 32f);

    camera.setToOrtho(false, 30, 20);

    miniMap = new MiniMap(map);
}

public void update(float x, float y){
    camera.position.x = x;
    camera.position.y = y;
    camera.update();
    //renderer.setView(camera.combined, x - 10, y - 10, 20, 20);    
    renderer.setView(camera);

    miniMap.update(x, y);
}

public void update(HostPlayer player){
    this.update(player.position.x + (player.skin.getWidth()/2f)/32f, player.position.y + (player.skin.getHeight()/2f)/32f); 
}

public void render(HostPlayer player){
    renderer.render();
    renderer.getBatch().begin();
    renderer.getBatch().draw(player.skin, player.position.x, player.position.y, 1/32f * player.skin.getWidth(), 1/32f * player.skin.getHeight());
    renderer.getBatch().end();

    miniMap.render();
}
```

And my MiniMap:

```
public class MiniMap {

private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer  renderer;
private OrthographicCamera          camera = new OrthographicCamera();

public MiniMap(TiledMap map) {

    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1 / 32f);

    camera.setToOrtho(false, 30, 20);

    camera.zoom = 10;
}

public void update(){

}

public void update(float x, float y){

    //Pixventure.instance.gameScreen.getCamera()

    camera.position.x = x;
    camera.position.y = y;
    camera.update();

    renderer.setView(camera.combined, x-15, y-15, 30, 30);  
    //renderer.setView(camera); 
}

public void render(){
    renderer.render();
}

}
```

The whole situation is looking like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Minimap's camera position is updated by player position. Place your minimap at the corner and don't change his position by your `update()` method.

Comment: but how can i get the minimap in the corner? if the camera position is not relative to the player, it is moving around all over the screen